latest kubuntu installer wont boot on new pc
I got new pc, ryzen 7, x670 aorus elite ax mainboard, rx 7900xtx. Windows installs at somehow works, so i guess hw is OK. I have kubuntu 24.04.1 on flash drive ready to replace the windows. It boots on my lenovo laptop every single time, so I guess the installer is ok as well(tried both usb creator and just unzipping files to fat32 partition). On new pc grub shows, but either normal or safe graphics ends up with black screen. With/without secureboot enabled. Tried with dp, hdmi, hdmi in integrated gpu. Always just black screen, forever. The laptop boost under minute, a lot more powerfull desktop wont boot in 5 minutes.
Any idea what can I try?

Start a live session?

@kyodake what does that mean? If you mean start ubuntu from usb, like 'try before install' — yes, this is what does not work.

Try creating the usb with yumi: https://pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

@kyodake I guess I can, but I don't give this much chances for success — as said, I tried 2 methods of creation, both work on lenovo laptop, neither on desktop. In uefi-only mode it's just copying files on flashdrive. I don't think there can realistically be some hiccup in that which could explain why it does not work on desktop while it does on laptop...

Try another distribution: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mx-linux/files/Final/KDE/MX-23.4_KDE_x64.iso/download

I would suspect compatibility problems with the graphics chip/card, maybe that the hardware is too new for the graphics drivers of that version of Kubuntu. You could try the newest possible version, 24.10.

@sudodus you're probably right, thanks for recommendation. I got that feeling during upset-sleep, I will try that kubuntu and if it does not work, I will try something bleeding edge like arch, but 24.10 was released pretty recently. I will keep you posted. Thanks again.

@sudodus no idea what that is. recap: on lenovo laptop I can boot 24.01,24.10,arch. On  new desktop none of them ⨯ (safe graphics, normal) ⨯ (hdmi, dp, integrated gpu hdmi). Latest bios drivers. It seems that I'm out of luck. From what I read 9800X3d should work even with 24.01, same with RX 7900 XTX. Very surprising that windows does not have problem — well aside of being windows. Their UI is worse with every version.

You could try in text mode (testing Ubuntu Server) either from the iso file or from a compressed image of an installed system. In this latter case, please start by reading the whole thread before starting to download, extract etc. -- Testing in text mode would help getting closer to where you have the problem.

@sudodus the arch was installed in text mode. Did not boot. I also already tested if it isn't caused by my big monitor, but that laptop gladly booted into text mode over usb-c->hdmi onto 34" screen. So it is not screen either. I've read that some reported that they had to swith from usb3 to usb2 etc. in order to boot. I will try another (worse) flashdrive, and more ports (I know that 1 isn't even recognised by bios at boot, while later it works) and I found some recomended bios tweaking...

I didn't confirm it myself yet(sharing sooner if someone needs it), but allegedly  the issue was caused by bios feature on gigabyte motherboard named "x3d turbo" [1]. When this is turned off (default), the linux won't boot.
[1] — (a revolutionary feature designed to maximize gaming performance on X870E, X870, and 600 series motherboards with AMD Ryzen™ 7000 X3D and Ryzen™ 9000 series processors)

Thanks for sharing what is probably a solution :-)
